# React-native sync storage solution

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

In native iOS code, I could use the `NSUserDefaults` to store and fetch data, which are sync operations. In react-native the offer is to use `AsyncStorage`, but I need a solution for sync storing, like `NSUserDefaults`.
I'm gonna use the result of data fetching to determine which screen to show, but since it's async I always get undefined when trying to fetch the persisted data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

after calling

> AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperStore:key');

react-native will call native function dependent on your platform in other thread 
then it will return a promise to resolve it 
,so if call like this

```
  let value =  AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperStore:key');
   value ++;
```

your value is not valid cause it data will be available later
the correct way to do is  :

```
try {
  const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperStore:key');
  if (value !== null){
    // We have data!!
    console.log(value);
  }
} catch (error) {
  // Error retrieving data
}
```

other way of doing this is

```
  try {
      AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperStore:key',(value )=>{  
      if (value !== null){
        // We have data!!
    console.log(value);
  }});

} catch (error) {
  // Error retrieving data
}
```

Comment: by the way if you use  native method you should use native-module of facebook for data interaction that probably fire promise

Answer (score 1):

you could make it asynchronous for example

```
   getData = async () => {
       const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('Yourkey');
        this.setState({key: value})

  }
```

Comment: then how to call `getData` ? if you don't return value